# Rails Application Templates: How to override lines already presents in environment files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

[Rails application templates](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) are great to quickly setup a base project.

But when I'm using the "environment" directive, to add some default configuration, it doesn't override already existing settings.

For example, if I set this line in my app template :

```
environment 'config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true', env: 'development'
```

It's added at top of my `config/environments/development.rb` file. But that doesn't override the existing line below

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

Is there a way to override existing lines ? (or at least a directive to delete a line matching a certain pattern)

Comment: There is nothing as overridden for lines. Methods can be overridden but not lines. Comment out line that you don't want and write a line that you want. That simple.

Comment: I talk about "application templates". The goal is to NOT having to edit files manually to comment/uncomment/change anything. I added an answer which permits to alter lines from an application template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Rails application template generator is based on [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor), it's possible to use gsub_file to remove a part of a file. So in this case:

```
gsub_file('config/environments/development.rb', /config\.action_mailer\.raise_delivery_errors.*/, '')
```

Comment: Thor also has a `comment_lines` action which can be handy for an application template: `comment_lines 'Gemfile', /coffee-rails/`